# Is there a recommended way to get real time data for a webapp?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

Let's say I want to tap into the outputs of Azure stream analytics or an Azure function app from an asp.net webapp for real time data analytics visualization.

While I could have a nodejs server peek my Azure storage and give the ability to fulfill clients with real-time data through websocket, is there an Azure module that does what I would implement?

Is there a recommended way of doing it? Preferably without having to peek directly into the storage.

---

#### Resolved

I finally used SignalR to tap into an Azure Service Bus which was fed from different sources and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

[Azure Time Series Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-overview) is one option to consider.

Comment: While it is certainly interesting to have a premade package for visualization, my goal is to ingest the data into my solution. I am looking into service bus topics which for now seem like the way to go.